# Расположить картинки по 3 в ряд

Tags: html, css

Нужна помощь, есть 7 картинок, нужно расположить их в 2 ряда по 3 и 1 снизу по центру, но еще под каждой картинкой нужен текст, что-то типо должности. Попробовал сделать так:

```css
  .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .item {
      flex-basis: 33%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .item-box {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .item:last-child {
      flex-basis: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
          <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" / style="width:40%">
          <p style="color:black">Manager</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
          <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" / style="width:40%"
          <p style="color:black">Manager</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
          <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" / style="width:40%"
          <p style="color:black">Manager</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
          <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="" / style="width:40%"
          <p style="margin-top:20px">Manager</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
          <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" / style="width:40%"
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
         <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" / style="width:40%">
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
          <img src="img/7.jpg" alt="" / style="width:40%"
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Но при определенных размерах картинок текст съезжает вправо от картинки.

Comment: [так](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/zyPPmp?editors=0110)?

Answer (score 1):

Решение на flexbox.

P.S. Проверяйте верстку, что это за `<img src="img/4.jpg" alt="" / style="width:40%`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 1 calc(100%/3 - 20px*2);
  margin: 20px;
}

.item-box {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-box img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/370x370" alt=""/>
          <p style="color:black">Manager</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/370x370" alt="" />
          <p style="color:black">Manager</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/370x370" alt=""/>
          <p style="color:black">Manager</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/370x370" alt=""/>
          <p style="margin-top:20px">Manager</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/370x370" alt=""  />
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
         <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/370x370" alt=""/>
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-box">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/370x370" alt=""/>
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то простое вроде этого:

```css
.imgs {
 width: 624px;
}
.imgs > .img {
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
}
.imgs > .img > img {
 border: 2px solid red;
 border-radius: 20%;
 margin-top: 3px;
}
.imgs > .img > span {
 border: 1px solid #d0e;
 background: #000;
 color: #bed;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgs">
 <div class="img">
  <img src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/893/thumb-89303.gif">
  <br/><span>Rookie</span>
 </div>
 <div class="img">
  <img src="http://chan.catiewayne.com/c/src/138578149239.png">
  <br/><span>Worker</span>
 </div>
 <div class="img">
  <img src="http://punkerslut.com/graphics-library-of-revolution-and-social-justice/anonymous-and-anonymous-movement/vectorportal---1/vectorportal---1__200x200.jpg">
  <br/><span>Secretary</span>
 </div>
 <div class="img">
  <img src="http://www.mallvarna.com/files/rte/article33/batux-tux-g2-hd-200x200.png">
  <br/><span>Admin</span>
 </div>
 <div class="img">
  <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/weboflife/images/b/b8/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BB.png/revision/latest?cb=20150527113023&path-prefix=ru">
  <br/><span>Boss</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Какой float? Воууу, не нужно так делать